# Would it be possible to run Ruby (possibly JRuby) on a Sun Spot? If so How?

Tags: java, ruby, jruby

this is probably a very naive question but im gonna ask it anyway.
I recently got a kit of [Sun Spot's](http://www.sunspotworld.com/) and I was wondering if it would be possible to run ruby on the buggers.
I immediately thought about JRuby, but because of lack of knowledge about Java Vm's I'm afraid that's a lost cause.
If it is, what would it take?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that SunSpot runs on Squawk (http://labs.oracle.com/projects/squawk/squawk-sunspot.html) that is a Java ME JVM with CLDC 1.1 configuration and IMP profile.

I have never tried it before, but you should look for a specific JRuby porting for CLDC. Maybe this post could be a start: http://blog.headius.com/2009/02/jruby-on-java-me.html